# Android can't kill application. Application restarts

Tags: android

I use a custom exception handler which defined in Application class :

```
  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
            {
                StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
                ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
                StringBuilder errorReport = new StringBuilder();
                errorReport.append("************ CAUSE OF ERROR ************\n\n");
                errorReport.append(stackTrace.toString());

                errorReport.append("\n************ DEVICE INFORMATION ***********\n");
                errorReport.append("Brand: ");
                errorReport.append(Build.BRAND);
                errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
                errorReport.append("Device: ");
                errorReport.append(Build.DEVICE);
                errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
                errorReport.append("Model: ");
                errorReport.append(Build.MODEL);
                errorReport.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);

                File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/.helper/crashes/");
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

                File file = new File(dir, "log.txt");

                try {
                    BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
                    buf.append(currentDateTimeString + ":" + errorReport.toString());
                    buf.newLine();
                    buf.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);
            }
        });
```

In OnCreate in MainActivity i simulate exception :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);
    throw new NullPointerException("Example");
}
```

Application was killed but restarts immediately. And this happens infinity. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i just swap lines :

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);
```

to

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Android OS interprets that it is a crash in activity. OS will auto-recreate the activity.

In your case, it is the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the normal behavior and you're not doing anything wrong.

You probably can set `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` for the activity in the manifest in order to prevent it from restarting itself (not tested but details can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish).

You can also understand a bit more about what's going on when the app is unexpectedly shutdown if you look at the answer posted by Wildroid: [What happens when App crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742747/what-happens-when-app-crashes).